# Add WCF custom certificate validation programatically

Tags: c#, wcf, validation, ssl

I'm trying to access a WebService that requires a certificate issued by themselves, and I'm getting errors during the validation.

```
BasicHttpsBinding _binding;
EndpointAddress _address;
X509Certificate2 _certificate;

public ServiceAccess() //Constructor
{
    _binding = new BasicHttpsBinding(BasicHttpsSecurityMode.TransportWithCredential);
    //With Credential because I've read on many tutorials that if I don't use this mode, 
    //IIS will validate the certificate first and fail without ever calling my custom validator

    _certificate = new X509Certificate2(); //I don't know why 2 except for the identity code below
    Byte[] bytes = Loader.EmbeddedResources.ToByteArray("Namespace.Project.certificate.crt");
    _certificate.Import(bytes);

    EndpointIdentity identity = EndpointIdentity.Create509CertificateIdentity(_certificate);

    _address = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("https://www.service.com/secure"), identity);
}

public void Start()
{
    ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient(_binding, _address);
    client.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.Custom;
    client.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CustomCertificateValidator = new CustomCertificateValidator();

    client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = _certificate; //why do I need to set this certificate again if I already defined it in the endpointAddress?

    try
    {
        client.DoSomething();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Error estabilishing a secure connection
        //Error the certificate doesn't have a private key
    }
}
```

And my Custom Validator:

```
public class CustomValidator : X509CertificateValidator
{
    public override void Validate(X509Certificate2 certificate)
    {
        //This never gets called
        throw new Exception("Custom Validator Called!");
    }
}
```

Since the certificate was issued by themselves, I'd like to add the custom validator to debug and make it skip whatever's causing the validation errors, but keep everything else as is. 
How can I make this work?

Comment: Error about private key is saying that you only have the public part. You need public to encrypt and private to decrypt. Make sure you have public AND private on both servers and try again. For more info Google "Asymmetric cryptography".

Comment: @Belogix I don't know much about certificates but, isn't the private key only accessible to the one providing the service/access? I don't have access to the server except than going to the URL and exporting the certificate from the browser.

Comment: Depends how you are doing it... 
Encrypt using private means you can decrypt using public.
Encrypt using public means you can decrypt with private.